# SQL ORACLE Select DATE

Tags: sql, date, select, oracle11g

I want to select all dates with are mondays

```
SELECT * 
FROM EMPLOYEES 
WHERE 
    (SELECT to_char(HIRE_DATE, 'DAY') FROM EMPLOYEES) = 'MONDAY';
```

HIRE_DAY is DATE type with format: MM:DD:YYYY e.g. '06/17/2003','09/21/2005'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If HIRE_DATE is really date type, you can simply run

```
SELECT * FROM EMPLOYEES WHERE TO_CHAR(HIRE_DATE,'DAY')='MONDAY'
```

Just wanted to add that date type does not have any "format". How the date column is displayed depends only on your tool and session settings.

Comment: Funny thing ur command didnt work but (!)  when i changed to 
SELECT * FROM EMPLOYEES WHERE TO_CHAR(HIRE_DATE,'D')='2'
It had gone thro, i dont know why :( maybe is something wrong with my DB. Thanks for help!

Comment: @hakobot: `'D'` returns the _number_ of the weekday. `'DAY'` returns the _name_ of the week day. See the manual for details: https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/sql_elements004.htm#SQLRF00212

Comment: SELECT * FROM EMPLOYEES WHERE TO_CHAR(HIRE_DATE,'DAY') LIKE 'MONDAY%' This is correct answer for my question. It seems like it was empty mark at end :(

Answer (score 0):

This is the query to list all the information from the table belonging to day "Monday"..

This will work

```
SELECT * 
FROM EMPLOYEES 
WHERE TO_CHAR(TO_DATE(HIRE_DATE,'dd/mm/yyyy'),'DAY')='MONDAY';
```

Comment: It didint help, in result i have ORA-01843: not a valid month
if i change in your comand: 'dd/mm/yyyy' to 'mm/dd/yyyy' in result i have no data found but im 100% sure that in my databes are dates with mondays :)

Comment: select TO_CHAR(TO_DATE('03/09/1982','mm/dd/yyyy'), 'DAY') from dual..Try this ..If this works and you having same date format ..It will Surely works bro @hakobot

Comment: As `HIRE_DATE` is already a `date` applying `to_date()` on it to convert the `date` value into a `date` value makes no sense at all.